# The criteria for choosing the top question

Tags: discussion

I can't understand, how the top questions of week/month are chosen. There is a question with more up-votes and it's in a lower rank than a question with fewer up-votes. On the other hand, a higher, sum of up-votes of question + answers or having more views does not guaranty a higher rank. Can you explain, what the criteria for choosing the top question are?

Comment: Are you referring to https://askubuntu.com/?tab=week and https://askubuntu.com/?tab=month? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/371617 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/371617.